# Factory, Singleton, Best practices

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton, factory

I want to implement the factory pattern properly in Java. I've done it like this (code below), could anyone please point out if this is a "proper" way, or any design flaws?

my thoughts/restrictions are:

- something else must be able to subclass this factory, so i did NOT choose to make it an enum.
- i made it this factory a singleton so that there is no other factories running amuck
- i wanted to make it thread safe, so i chose to put synchronized lock on `self`
- there's not a TON of stuff that has to go on in the factory, so performance (space/time) is not too big of a deal

The code is something like:

```
public class MyFactory {
    private static MyFactory self;

    private MyFactory() {
        synchronized (self) {
            if (self == null) {
                self = new MyFactory();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would this piece of code ever give me issues?

The alternative is something like

```
public class MyFactory { 
    private static MyFactory self = new MyFactory();
}
```

which one is better, and what are the considerations for these types of lazy vs eager instantiation?

Comment: `synchronized (self)` my produce a `NullPointerException`, either use another `static final` object or synchronize the method.  The second example could allow two or threads to create more than one instance of the factory.

Comment: Factory and singleton are two different concepts and it is better handle them separate. Are you going to use any framework ? If yes , singleton should be responsibility of framework , e.g. Spring.

Comment: @MadProgrammer wait, really? i couldn't synchronize on a constructor (which i guess is equivalent to a static initializer?)

Comment: @yadab actually i was wondering about that - should factories be singletons?

Comment: @DavidT. Sorry, thought you were using a method like `getInstance`...

Comment: @DavidT you can not subclass a singleton and your use case says you want it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh yeah, i see what you mean. good point, i just forgot to write the other stuff

Comment: If Parent-Constructor is private then your child class will not have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One critique would be that the being able to subclass requirement and the singleton requirement are at odds - If you want to be able to subclass the factory, you will have to make the constructor not private, which makes the factory not singleton.

Comment: so are Factories supposed to be Singletons?

Comment: They usually are yes, but honestly don't let that stop you. If your implementation calls for something slightly different then just go for it - As long as its clean and easy to use and understand. Standards in patterns are a good guide for for keeping things that way but they aren't hard and fast rules where noone will understand your code if you step outside the lines.